# Is there a name for a known untruth being used as a defense or antagonistic tool?

Tags: single-word-requests, terminology

Is there a word for the perpetuation of a known lie as a plausibly deniable excuse for objectionable beliefs?

I'm thinking of the Lost Cause of the Civil War, which is an argument that the Civil War was about states' rights, and not about slavery. One can't help but think many people espousing the argument don't believe it, but it maintains the barest thread of plausibility, so it can exist as a defense or coping mechanism.

More recent is The Big Lie -- the "belief" that the 2020 presidential election was fraudulent and Donald Trump actually won. Again, many people espousing this scenario likely don't actually believe it, but use it simply as a tool of reality denial or antagonism of people they disagree with.

There are lots of pejorative names you could put on these, but is there a commonly accepted name for something like this? Is there an underlying psychological condition that gives this a formal name?

Comment: Closely related: [idiom / phrase for refusing to admit one's mistake ...](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/532882/any-idiom-or-phrase-for-refusing-to-admit-ones-mistake-or-ones-own-lack-of-kn/532894#532894): 'self-justification' and 'face-saving' are offered, but are hypernymic.

Comment: lie purveyors? There is no one term, I don't think.

Comment: It's gaslighting. I don't know if that's the sort of word you're looking for.

Comment: Perhaps distraction or misdirection. The underlying psychological condition is among OCD, megalomania, narcissism.

Comment: There doesn't need to be an underlying psychological condition. Deceit in order to influence change in the direction you'd like may be cynical, but it's not irrational.

Comment: Wikipedia says *the Lost Cause of the Civil War* is a "pseudohistorical negationist myth". But of course, there will be many people who take it fort granted that if mainstream opinion rejects that myth, they must agree that the American Civil War was all about the moral issue of slavery. But that strikes me as unlikely - almost certainly, that war was actually fought for ***economic*** reasons, the same as almost every war in history.

Comment: Specious argument? In denial?

Comment: @YosefBaskin I'll vote that as the answer if you add it.

Comment: You should include an example sentence with [the SWR tag](https://english.stackexchange.com/tags/single-word-requests/info).

Answer (score 0):

Merriam-Webster defines [truthiness](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/truthiness) as

> a truthful or seemingly truthful quality that is claimed for something not because of supporting facts or evidence but because of a feeling that it is true or a desire for it to be true

Merriam-Webster explains

> The Oxford English Dictionary provides evidence dating to the first half of the 19th century for the use of truthiness as a rare word synonymous with truthfulness. In its current sense, truthiness was coined and popularized by the American satirist Stephen Colbert, who first used it in 2005.

and give the following example sentences, among others

> Whether it's blind bias in favor of one's own sports team, an insistence that Republicans rigged the 2004 election, 9/11 conspiracy theories or AIDS skepticism, [Farhad] Manjoo concluded that the feeling that something is true had, for many, become a substitute for actual evidence. It's what Stephen Colbert called "truthiness."
> —S. E. Cupp
>
> Our whole social environment and each of its overlapping parts—cultural, religious, political, intellectual, psychological—have become conducive to spectacular fallacy and truthiness and make-believe.
> —Kurt Andersen
>
> Then came The Colbert Report, a satire of pundit programs that added truthiness to the national lexicon, a way of critiquing the steady American diet of political falsehoods disguised as facts.
> —Sascha Cohen, The Atlantic, 10 Sep. 2021
>
> Like it or not, human beings are highly susceptible to truthiness: research indicates that 50% of Americans believe in at least one conspiracy theory.
> —Kareem Saleh, Forbes, 4 May 2021

Wikipedia's page on [truthiness](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Truthiness) says

> Truthiness is the belief or assertion that a particular statement is true based on the intuition or perceptions of some individual or individuals, without regard to evidence, logic, intellectual examination, or facts.[1](https://eu.press-citizen.com/story/opinion/2022/09/16/opinion-psychological-concept-may-explain-those-who-believe-big-lie/8025549001/) Truthiness can range from ignorant assertions of falsehoods to deliberate duplicity or propaganda intended to sway opinions.[3](https://eu.press-citizen.com/story/opinion/2022/09/16/opinion-psychological-concept-may-explain-those-who-believe-big-lie/8025549001/)

According to Professor John S. Westefeld, when answering the question

> If something is seen as big, and is a lie, why is it still seen as truth by so many?

in his article [Opinion: Psychological concept may explain those who believe 'big lie' about 2020 election](https://eu.press-citizen.com/story/opinion/2022/09/16/opinion-psychological-concept-may-explain-those-who-believe-big-lie/8025549001/) the concept is known as “The Illusory Truth Effect”

> This idea first appeared in 1977 in a paper entitled “Frequency and the Conference of Referential Validity” by Hasher, Goldstein and Toppino in the Journal of Verbal Learning & Verbal Behavior.
>
> Since 1977, research has validated the ITE as a significant force. The Illusory Truth Effect fundamentally postulates that there is a tendency for some people to see untrue information as true, if exposed to that information repeatedly over time.
>
> ...
>
> I am sure we will continue to see endorsement of the big lie by many. However, the next time you encounter someone supporting it, consider introducing them to the concept of the ITE.
>
> And while it is of course unlikely that they will endorse the notion of the ITE, maybe it will at least give them pause, and they will consider the issue further. And just maybe they will stop endorsing the big lie — no matter how many times they hear it repeated

Comment: The OP says knowingly, so this does not work.